# Why can't I open matlab .m files from a server

Tags: matlab, user-interface, server

I just upgraded to MATLAB R2021b (Windows 8) and now when I try to save a MATLAB file to a server that my office uses, the editor tab changes to look like this:
[image: editor tab matlab 2021b]

Also if I try to open a file that is already saved in the server, nothing happens. It works fine when I work directly from my computer, but I prefer to work from the server.

I just go to the working folder on the server (e.g. `\\Server_2\My_files\09_29_21`) and double click the code from the current folder tab or write in the command window `open experiment` if the file is called "experiment.m”.

Comment: OS is Windows 8.1. I believe the protocol is TCP/IP. I just go to the working folder on the server (e.g. \\Server_2\My_files\09_29_21) and double click the code from the current folder tab or write in the command window "open experiment" if the file is called "experiment.m

Comment: I’ve added this relevant information to your question.

Comment: Are you saying that this used to work with an older version of MATLAB? If so, I would suggest you submit a bug report! In the meantime, does this work correctly if you assign a drive letter to the networked drive?

Comment: yes it worked for matlab2019a